# Python multilevel getattr with string

Tags: python, object, attributes, getattr

I have a function (here called `analyze_data`) that takes an object and a string as input, and uses the string to "extract" data via `getattr`. This works fine when the data are in the "frist" level of attributes (`data1`). However, I don't know what I can pass to the function to access the data when they are in a lower level (`data2`). Passing a dotted string (as shown below) does not work.

```
class a:
    pass

instance1 = a()

# Create 1st data set
instance1.data1 = [1,2,3]

# Create 2nd data set
instance1.subdata = a()
instance1.subdata.data2 = [4,5,6]


def analyze_data(myvar, dataname):
    data = getattr(myvar, dataname)
    # Do something with data, e.g.:
    print(str(data[0]))
    
analyze_data(instance1, 'data1')
analyze_data(instance1, 'subdata.data2')
```

What is the best way to access `data2` without changing the existing function `analyze_data` too much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `getattr` you should use [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) which allows you to specify using the dot notation. This does require a minor change to your function as shown below.

```
from operator import attrgetter

def analyze_data(myvar, dataname):
    fn = attrgetter(dataname)
    data = fn(myvar)
    # Do something with data, e.g.:
    print(str(data[0]))

analyze_data(instance1, 'data1')
1

analyze_data(instance1, 'subdata.data2')
4
```

Answer (score 1):

`functools.reduce` is another option.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(getattr, 'subdata.data2'.split('.'), instance1)
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want without changing the function at all is this:

```
class a:
pass

instance1 = a()

# Create 1st data set
instance1.data1 = [1,2,3]

# Create 2nd data set
instance1.subdata = a()
instance1.subdata.data2 = [4,5,6]


def analyze_data(myvar, dataname):
    data = getattr(myvar, dataname)
    # Do something with data, e.g.:
    print(str(data[0]))

analyze_data(instance1, 'data1')
analyze_data(instance1.subdata, 'data2')
```

Comment: Very good answer! The only reason I did not do it this way is because in reality my `analyze_data` is more complex and does not take `instance1` directly as in argument, but a list of instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can recurse into the data by splitting the dotted path and following it:

```
def analyze_data(myvar, dataname):
    for dn in dataname.split('.'):
        myvar = getattr(myvar, dn)
    # Do something with data, e.g.:
    print(str(myvar[0]))
```

This keeps updating `myvar` until you are at the end of the path.

Comment: The answer does not deserve to be downvoted. It explicitly demonstartes the logic of the solution. That's how `attrgetter` does the job.

Comment: I tried to follow the brief and not modify the function "too much" instead of using a library or clever one-liner to obfuscate it.